# Координаты объекта в Canvas

Tags: c#, wpf, координаты, wpf-canvas

Какие нужно вызвать свойства у объекта `rectangle` в коде, чтобы узнать текущие координаты в `canvas'e`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вопрос закрыт

```
double x = Canvas.GetLeft(rectangle1);
double y = Canvas.GetTop(rectangle1);
```